# not getting expected result from sql query select python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to select from a specific row and then column in SQL.
I want to find a specific user_name row and then select the access_id from the row.

Here is all of my code.

```
import sys, ConfigParser, numpy
import MySQLdb as mdb
from plaid.utils import json

class SQLConnection:
    """Used to connect to a SQL database and send queries to it"""
    config_file = 'db.cfg'
    section_name = 'Database Details'

_db_name = ''
_hostname = ''
_ip_address = ''
_username = ''
_password = ''

def __init__(self):
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read(self.config_file)
    print "making"

    try:
        _db_name = config.get(self.section_name, 'db_name')
        _hostname = config.get(self.section_name, 'hostname')
        _ip_address = config.get(self.section_name, 'ip_address')
        _user = config.get(self.section_name, 'user')
        _password = config.get(self.section_name, 'password')
    except ConfigParser.NoOptionError as e:
        print ('one of the options in the config file has no value\n{0}: ' +
            '{1}').format(e.errno, e.strerror)
        sys.exit()


    self.con = mdb.connect(_hostname, _user, _password, _db_name)
    self.con.autocommit(False)
    self.con.ping(True)

    self.cur = self.con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)


def query(self, sql_query, values=None):
        """
        take in 1 or more query strings and perform a transaction
        @param sql_query: either a single string or an array of strings
            representing individual queries
        @param values: either a single json object or an array of json objects
            representing quoted values to insert into the relative query
            (values and sql_query indexes must line up)
        """
        #  TODO check sql_query and values to see if they are lists
        #  if sql_query is a string
        if isinstance(sql_query, basestring):
            self.cur.execute(sql_query, values)
            self.con.commit()
        #  otherwise sql_query should be a list of strings
        else:
            #  execute each query with relative values
            for query, sub_values in zip(sql_query, values):
                self.cur.execute(query, sub_values)
            #  commit all these queries
            self.con.commit
        return self.cur.fetchall


def get_plaid_token(self,username):
        result= self.query("SELECT access_id FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` LIKE %s",[username])
        print type (result)
        return result


print SQLConnection().get_plaid_token("test")
```

I would like the get the transaction ID but for some reason "result" returns

> ```
> > <bound method DictCursor.fetchall of <MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor
> > object at 0x000000000396F278>>
> ```

result is also of type `"instancemethod"`

Comment: What does autocommit and ping do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing this line:

```
return self.cur.fetchall
```

to

```
return self.cur.fetchall()
```

Without the parentheses after the method name, you are returning a reference to that method itself, not running the method.

Comment: @gordonLinoff I will accept the answer. I have to wait 10 minutes before I can however.